# dev_appserver fails to launch on Ubuntu docker container (ValidationError: Value 'None' for application does not match expression)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu-16.04

I started seeing this issue after upgrading docker container. I couldn't find a way to use an older package for app engine. Using options =157.x.y to get older versions doesn't work in `apt-get`.

**Failure log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 103, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 322, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 310, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 106, in start
    env_variables=parsed_env_variables)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 851, in __init__
    env_variables)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 131, in __init__
    self._config_path)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 443, in _parse_configuration
    config.application = self._forced_app_id
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/validation.py", line 361, in __setattr__
    value = self.GetValidator(key)(value, key)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/validation.py", line 599, in __call__
    return self.Validate(value, key)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/validation.py", line 881, in Validate
    return self.validator(value, key)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/validation.py", line 599, in __call__
    return self.Validate(value, key)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/validation.py", line 955, in Validate
    '\'%s\'' % (value, key, self.re.pattern))
google.appengine.api.validation.ValidationError: Value 'None' for application does not match expression '^(?:(?:[a-z\d\-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!\-)[a-z\d\-\.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,99}[a-z\d])$'
```

**Docker file**

```
    FROM ubuntu:16.04
    RUN apt-get upgrade
    RUN apt-get update

    RUN apt-get install -y wget
    RUN apt-get install -y curl
    RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

    RUN echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

    RUN wget -O - https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -

    RUN apt-get update
    RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

    RUN apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk
    RUN apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python

    WORKDIR /mycodepath
    EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My version of dev_appserver started doing the same.

I dug onto the code and found that the argument parser sets an empty app_id command-line argument to `"None"` (yes, that's a String not a NoneType). Incidentally, the app_id regex does not match for uppercase characters and thus the ValidationError triggers. (I'm glad that's the case or else it would've caused trickier bugs by silently making my application's name 'None')

My workaround for now is to explicitly pass in the name of your application from the command line with the `-A` flag. Note that this overrides the `application` variable in the app.yaml configuration.

I was thinking my version of argparse was broken but now it sounds like a dev_appserver bug.